# Converting unknown type of coordinates to lat/lon

Tags: gps, coordinate-system

Our company is using Total Station (Surveying Machine using SOP) to calculate GPS coordinates and its results are something like this

```
Easting: 3250193.00, Northing: 1115573.00, Elevation: 656.00
Easting: 3249214.00, Northing: 1111220.00, Elevation: 735.00
...
```

I want to convert these points to decimal based lat/lon (so that can map those points to google maps). Can someone help me out in converting these points?

The above points are somewhere near to Muzaffarabad, Azad Kashmir. (Some where near to 34.3629, 73.4775)

Comment: I would try a little harder to find out what coordinate system the eastings/northings are in. If they've come from fairly recent software there's a good chance that they're in WGS84 UTM and a zone that suits. You could try that and see how well they line up to known features - though if you're using Total Station you could expect sub-metre accuracy and this approach wont guarantee that.

Comment: No, its quite older way of getting the gps data in our company! I need to convert all older data into lat/lon :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EPSG:24378 Kalianpur 1975 / India I should be the local CRS in the region you mentioned. The extent seems to fit to that:

[image]

To get this picture using QGIS, create these text files:

```
E N
73.4775 34.3629
```

and

```
Easting Northing
3250193.00 1115573.00
3249214.00 1111220.00
```

Load each into QGIS as `Delimited Text File`, with blank as delimiter and setting CRS to EPSG:4326 for the first and EPSG:24378 for the second. Project CRS is EPSG:3857 to add Openstreetmap background with the openlayers plugin.

If the data is older than 1975, you might as well look for Kalianpur 1962 or Kalianpur 1880.

You can use GDAL cs2cs or ogr2ogr to reproject the data to any other CRS. For Google Maps, EPSG.4326 would be best.

Comment: How you calculated 73.4775 / 34.3629 ? Its looking very very close to the original point

Comment: I did not calculate it. QGIS allows to input data in any kind of CRS. It reprojects internally to the right point if the project CRS is different.

Comment: can you please provide steps??? I just installed QGIS and not sure where to put the Easting/Northing values

Comment: See my extended answer.